# How much RAM does a Huawei H868c Glory have?

Tags: ram, huawei

I want to run "Terraria" on my Huawei H868c Glory, which is running Android 4.0.4.

How much RAM does it have?

Answer (score 1):

The amount of RAM for the Huawei Glory (H868C) is **512MB** (390MB available to apps). According to Terraria via the Play Store:

> Optimized for Android OS 3+ and requires 512MB RAM.

So, you *should* be able to run it. If you are able to install it from the Play Store, then you will most likely be able to run it. It doesn't hurt to try.